# How to scroll to a div id in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe, scroll, jsni

I have a webpage with an iframe in which a gwt application is running. The webpage has a `<div id="head">`. It is not possible to scroll in the iframe (intended) so the webpage has for example a height of 1000px. At the very bottom there is a button and I want that when someone clicks on that button (note: the button is in the gwt application) then I want to scroll to the top.

That means that the iframe needs to force the parent window to scroll to the top. I tried it with a jsni function like this:

```
    public static native void scrollToTop()  /*-{
        $wnd.top.scrollTo(0,0);
    }-*/;
```

But this didn't work. So my new idea is to scroll to the div id "header". Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I tried it like this:

```
document.getElementById('header').scrollIntoView();
```

But that seems not to work (because it should be in a JSNI manner?).

Thanks for any inputs!

Answer (score 5):

It fails because GWT runs in an iframe, so `document` references the GWT's iframe, and not your "HTML host page". You have to use `$doc` in JSNI to reference the document (just like `$wnd` instead of `window`).

But you actually don't need JSNI for that; plain old Java/GWT will do:

```java
Document.get().getElementById("header").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Unless the "header" is in the webpage containing the iframe in which GWT runs. Then you can't access it.

Comment: With the plain old/GWT way I get an UmbrellaExeption. My feeling is that it can't find the div id="header" which is defined in the parent window.

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp : the "header" is in the webpage containing the iframe. This is the problem I'm trying to fix. I also tried it by having a javascript in the parent window (the webpage containing the iframe) and call that javascript function from the iframe. But then I have unsafe access exceptions because the webpage and the webpage in the iframe are from different addresses. I really have to somehow fix this problem and there is no solution without an iframe :(

Comment: If the containing page and the iframe have different security domains (they differ in at least one of protocol, domain and port) there is no solution to your problem - the browser will not allow programatic manipulation of one from the other under any circumstances.

Comment: This is a well discussed topic but have ever anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. You have to set an anchor at the top of your website (the website inside the iframe). Please look at my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667697/scrolling-a-page-to-the-top-from-an-iframe-containing-a-gwt-application) for more details.

P.S. I hope you see the importance of this post and upvote it. It will save a lot of time for other people.

Comment: Note that using an anchor will create a new History entry.

Comment: It won't do that but it solves the problem with focusing when GWT is embedded in an iframe.  When you have website in an iframe and clicking buttons in the iframe switches websites then you can do what many others have suggested (using onload tag in the iframe tag). If the solution was that obvious then I would have expected this solution much earlier. But no one was to able to solve it and now I found this simple solution and I just want that other people (who uses gwt in an iframe) must not spend a lot of time figuring this out.

Comment: yes I understand. It was just to make sure people understand the consequences. Also note that this problem only occurs when the webpage in the iframe is on another domain. Because in that situation you don't have access to `top.scrollTo`.