# how to make parent web page scroll to a specific position (at the top) from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

My problem is similar to this

[Scrolling a page to the top from an iframe (containing a gwt application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667697/scrolling-a-page-to-the-top-from-an-iframe-containing-a-gwt-application)

But my iframe is made with vb.net and asp.net. and the parent webpages are external. i.e Third party websites uses our iframe to integrate in their webpage. and the all functionality of our web application is performed inside the iframe.

there are number of pages and form in our iframe. among them one page causes the problem. when this page loads it makes the webpage scroll to the bottom of the page automatically.

i want to make the parent webpage scroll to the top of the page from a page inside the iframe ( without making the users  clicking on any button ).

how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the JavaScript's [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) function in the iFrame :

```
window.parent.scroll(0,0);
```